# JITWatch Launching TriView for null

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to run my own classes in JITWatch, however, I can only seem to get the prepackaged .java files in the sandbox/sources folder to work. Every time I run my own classes in the sandbox, I get the following in the console:

```
Parsing JIT log: C:\path\to\sandbox.log
Parsing complete
Looking up class: MyClassName
Launching TriView for null
```

The TriView window then opens up with nothing displayed.

I've tried sorting the issue by updating my JAVA_HOME env variable to Java 11, as JITWatch runs on Gradle 5.5.

The class I'm trying to get this working with is as follows:

```
public class MyClassName {
    public static void doIt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                System.out.println("Hello again");
                System.out.println("Hello one last time");
            }, String.valueOf(i));
            th.start();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClassName.doIt();
    }

}
```

I feel as though I'm missing something small. Any suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: So you are running like this? https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/wiki/Instructions#run-with-gradle

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue, but this does not seem to be the fault of JITWatch, though, the log file simply does not include anything about MyClassName...

I have manually compile and ran the [`SimpleInliningTest`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/examples/SimpleInliningTest.java), with that JITWatch shows output.

It seems your class is not touched by the JIT :)

Comment: I increased the number of iterations in the loop to an arbitrarily large number and it works now. I was expecting that if none of the class' members were JIT-compiled, then `Not JIT-compiled` would show in the Assembly pane in TriView (as is the case when a given class' members may only partly have been JIT-compiled), however, it seems that the actual behaviour where the number of iterations is small, is that the log file is basically just not written to, as you say.